# Jade unexpected length error

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug

How do i deal with this issue? My jade file is:

```
extends layout

block content
    h1.
        User List
    ul
        each user, i in userlist
            li
                a(href="mailto:#{user.email}")= user.username
```

i get the following error:

```
TypeError: C:\node\nodetest1\views\userlist.jade:7
    5|         User List
    6|     ul
  > 7|         each user, i in userlist
    8|             li
    9|                 a(href="mailto:#{user.email}")= user.username

Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (C:\node\nodetest1\node_modules\jade\lib\jade.js:174:8), <anonymous>:56:31)
    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (C:\node\nodetest1\node_modules\jade\lib\jade.js:174:8), <anonymous>:99:4)
    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (C:\node\nodetest1\node_modules\jade\lib\jade.js:174:8), <anonymous>:112:22)
    at res (C:\node\nodetest1\node_modules\jade\lib\jade.js:175:38)
    at Object.exports.render (C:\node\nodetest1\node_modules\jade\lib\jade.js:300:10)
    at Object.exports.renderFile (C:\node\nodetest1\node_modules\jade\lib\jade.js:336:18)
    at View.exports.renderFile [as engine] (C:\node\nodetest1\node_modules\jade\lib\jade.js:321:21)
    at View.render (C:\node\nodetest1\node_modules\express\lib\view.js:76:8)
    at Function.app.render (C:\node\nodetest1\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:527:10)
    at ServerResponse.res.render (C:\node\nodetest1\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:900:7)
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you haven't sent the `userlist` object to Jade. You need to render it like this:

```
res.render('userlist', {userlist: userlist});
```

Where the third occurrence of `userlist` there is your object.